# SonarQube upgrade 4.3.2 -> 5.1 fails

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube upgrade from 4.3.2 to 5.1 fails with

> INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
>   ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
>   org/sonar/api/rules/ViolationFilter

List of plugins

sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar    sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-1.1.jar  sonar-fortify-plugin-2.0.jar     sonar-quality-index-plugin-1.1.3.jar
sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar     sonar-java-plugin-3.1.jar        sonar-switch-off-violations-plugin-1.3.jar
sonar-clover-plugin-3.0.jar         sonar-javascript-plugin-2.5.jar  sonar-violationdensity-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar    sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar        sonar-widget-lab-plugin-1.7.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-3.3.jar         sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar         sonar-xml-plugin-1.2.jar

Could some one help me resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Deprecated+Plugins, the switchoff and quality-index plugins are deprecated since SonarQube 4.0. They should be uninstalled.
To avoid such errors, it's recommended to browse the administration page named "Update Center" before upgrading plugins and SonarQube.

Comment: Thank you, removing those plugins solved th problem. Update center never complained about those two plugins though, only plugin it complained was JMeter.